# Will I be able to fresh install Windows 11 using my Windows 10 key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

I'm currently using a PC with **Microsoft Windows 10 Pro** v10.0.19045 Build 19045, and I can retrieve the genuine license key with command `wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey`

I'm also going to buy a new PC, replacing this one. The new PC will come with no OS installed. I'm thinking to install **Windows 11 22H2** using an ISO from the [official tool](https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/software-download/windows11).

Assuming the installation will ask me for a valid license key, will I be able to use the one from my current Windows 10 PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can retrieve the genuine license key......

**(A)** You can only move this key / license to a new computer if and only if the original license was a Retail License (non OEM).  If that is so, you can move the license and upgrade to Windows 11.

OR

**(B)** Most computers are OEM licensed.  If your original license is OEM, then you cannot move it to a new computer. An upgrade will eventually fail licensing check.

Comment: Is there a way to check if my key is Retail or OEM? I had several keys in my experience and I cannot remember the origin of this one.

EDIT: by running `slmgr /dli` it shows a prompt telling that I'm in the "Retail channel"!

Comment: Right click My Computer and then Properties.   If Product ID has OEM in the license string then it is OEM.

Comment: I ran slmr here and it said OEM channel (true).  So if your license is Retail, then you should be good to go

Comment: Windows 10 keys will activate an equivalent edition of Windows 11. The only exception to that statement is editions that have VLK (Volume License Keys)which doesn’t apply to Home and Professional editions of Windows 10. However, all of those extensions, are licensed in such a way where an upgrade to their equivalent editions are likely included.